# MS Access Form Style

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

My question is about styling the form.
If I Create a "Split Form" in ms access, it's design is in flatty style:
[image: Pic. 1]

But Whenever I create a form from "Form Design" it has an old styled edges design:
[image]
I'm using MS Access 2013. Tryed to change the formatting options but with no success. Is there any way I can make a form design flatty like in the split form?

Comment: What OS are you on? With my Access 2013/Windows 10 install I can only get the flat look to appear. Do you have more than 1 version of Access installed?

Comment: I have only one MS Office version on my Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

That is controlled by the [`Form.BorderStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821190.aspx) Property.

The first one is probably "Thin", the second is "Sizable".

Comment: nope. Both is "Sizable" and changing it does not make a difference

Comment: The split form may have special settings that override the BorderStyle. But I very much doubt that if you change the second form to "Thin", that it will still look like in your screenshot. @TedoG.

Comment: Checked again the format properties.  It really is "Thin" and really looks like what I shown you :-/ Could not even find the other properties that may override BorderStyle

Comment: Hm, ok. It may be Access 2013-specific.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have got a reference (VBE - Tools - References) to the `Microsoft Access 12.0 Object library` instead of the `Microsoft Access 15.0 Object library`

Comment: You're wrong, I have `Microsoft Access 15.0 Object library` and `Microsoft Office 15.0 Object library`.